# PHP iCal loop script - only bringing in one date

Tags: php, icalendar

I've been trying to create an iCal feed to take dates from my custom database. So far I can get the script to echo out the dates and it validates ok here http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/
..but when I import into Google, it adds the calender but with no dates and when I import into iPad, I just get the first date and nothing else.

Here's the code that i'm using (which I've pieced together from snippets that I've found around the net).

```
<? 
// Connects to your Database 
include (ABSPATH.'/connect_include.php');

}
mysql_select_db($database_name, $connection); // makes other mysql_ functions act on        this database
 echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n"; //some static ical headers
        echo "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
        echo "PRODID:-//www.the-guards.co.uk gig bible ical feed v1//EN\r\n";
        echo "X-WR-CALNAME:Gig Dates\r\n";
        echo "X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London\r\n";
        echo "X-WR-CALDESC:Private gig diary.\r\n";

$query  = " … "; /* [SQL Query] */

$result = mysql_query($query);
define('DATE_ICAL', 'Ymd\THis\Z');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo 
"BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n".
"UID:{$row['id']}\r\n".
"SUMMARY:{$row['location_name']}\r\n".
"DTSTART:" .date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime("{$row['starts']}"))."\r\n".
"DTEND:" .date(DATE_ICAL, strtotime("{$row['ends']}"))."\r\n".
"END:VEVENT\r\n"
;
echo  "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Also, is there anything that I need to include to ensure that changes to dates are always kept up to date in the host application?
....the main reason that I'm doing this is that iPad/iPhone Safari browsers refresh upon opening - so if I need to check a date in my calender database in an area that has no wifi/3G I cannot see the data - If I can import the data (and any changes) into a calendar app then I should be able to at least see the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Oh......spotted my own error!

I put the 'END:VCALENDAR' tag inside the loop!

...it's amazing what ten minutes away from the code will do!